# Dataframe doubling the total number of rows

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, rvest

I'm running the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

commits_url <- paste0("https://247sports.com/Season/2022-Football/Commits/?Page=", 1:7)

commits_school_gather <- map_df(commits_url, ~.x %>% read_html %>%
                                  html_nodes('div.status img') %>%
                                  html_attr('title') %>%
                                  matrix(ncol = 1, byrow = T) %>% 
                                  as.data.frame)
```

This should return 238 rows (at least as of this moment, at 05:36 PM EST on 03/05/2021. Just noting this for future documentation because that number will change over time). When I run the code, it returns 476 rows, which is precisely double the amount I expect.

If you run `commits_school_gather %>% head(10)` it looks as such:

```
V1
Rutgers
Rutgers
Notre Dame
Notre Dame
Michigan
Michigan
Akron
Akron
Notre Dame
Notre Dame
```

I would like the output to look as such:

```
V1
Rutgers
Notre Dame
Michigan
Akron
Notre Dame
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the css selector in the html_nodes() step was picking up two nodes inside the 'dic.status img' path.

Try this instead:

```
commits_school_gather <- map_df(commits_url, ~.x %>% read_html %>%
                              html_nodes('div.status img.jsonly') %>%
                              html_attr('title') %>%
                              matrix(ncol = 1, byrow = T) %>% 
                              as.data.frame)
```

### Results

```
                   V1
1             Rutgers
2          Notre Dame
3            Michigan
4               Akron
5             Clemson
6              Oregon
7            Oklahoma
8             Arizona
9              Kansas
10  Mississippi State
...
```

## Explaining the error:

Look how the original css = 'div.status img' will pick the nodes in lines 3 AND 5. The alternative css fixes the query to the first node only.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rleid`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
commits_school_gather %>%
   filter(!duplicated(rleid(V1)))
```

Comment: Apologies, I should have been clearer. That returns 71 values. I'm not looking for distinct values. I just edited the output/expected output to better demonstrate what I mean. You'll now notice that `Notre Dame` appears twice because it's expected to appear twice. Again, the total number of rows should be 238. Again, not looking for distinct values, I'm trying to understand why this is doubling the total expected and how to fix it.

Comment: @LeTigris I updated the post with `rleid`.  didn't notice that second notredam

Comment: @LeTigris I get 228 rows after the filtering